# How do the fields in the subscription button work in HTML? I thought I knew, but I'm getting mixed signals.

Tags: php, paypal, recurring-billing

I've coded up my own "Subscription" button to try to generate a recurring (monthly) payment for 12 months. I'm referencing the PayPal Developer "HTML Variables for PayPal Payment Standard" documentation, and have come up with the following code:

---

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="ITMgmt_Subscribe_WPS-CA">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="alan.douglas@ITMgmt.biz">
<table>
<tr><td>Assign Amount to:</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="item_name" value="<enter designation>"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="CAD"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Monthly Amount:</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="a3" value="30.00"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="p3" value="12"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="t3" value="M"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1"></td></tr>
<tr><td>In memoriam:</td></tr>
<tr><td>Donor name:<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Donor Name"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="os0" size="100" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Set up recurring payments easily!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

From what I understand, this should set up a payment of $30/month for 12 months, and when I click the button, that seems to be what it's done:

```
`Description: Construction Fund               
`Terms:       $30.00 CAD for 12 months    Effective Date: Jan 28, 2014                        
`Amount:      $30.00 CAD
```

`However, besides my not having any control over the Effective Date, the notification that is`generated to the "customer" reads:

---

`You sent an automatic payment

---

Transaction ID: 32U363747H730390R
    `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/ca/vst/id=32U363747H730390R`

Hello AL DOUGLAS,

You sent an automatic payment to Alan Douglas's Test Store. Here are the details:

---

Amount:$30.00 CAD
To:Alan Douglas's Test Store
For:Construction Fund
Customer service URL:`http://www.helloworld.com`
Customer service email:`alan.douglas@ITmgmt.biz`

Automatic payment details

---

`Automatic payment number:I-3K9JR0U78EBT

`Amount to be paid each time:$30.00 CAD

`Billing cycle:Every 12 Months <================================= ????

`Payments start:Jan 28, 2014 <================================= ????

`Payments stop after cycle:1 <================================= ????

`Pay with money from:Bank Of Canada Chequing (Confirmed) x-6211

The lines above, marked "????" are telling the "customer" that he's effectively made a one-time payment of $30, rather than a monthly, recurring payment of $30 for 12 months.

What actually happened was that a one-time payment was made.

Comment: please read the html variables from here and use according to your requirements.   https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

Answer (score 0):

p3 should be a 1 so that it will be every 1 month.  I don't believe Standard subscriptions provide the ability to specify an end date.  For that you would need to move to Express Checkout and the Recurring Payments API.  With Standard the profile would need to be canceled to stop it.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. After some more browsing and experimentation, I managed to find variables src (set to 1 for recurring payment, defaults to 0) and srt (value between 1 and 52 for # of occurrences).

Comment: The only thing I can't do now is set the effective date. The recurring payments start on the current date and repeat on the same day in the following months; if the day doesn't exist, the end of the month is used (ie: Jan 31, Feb 28, Mar 31, Apr 30 ...).

Comment: I'm assuming the only way to tackle the effective date is to use some PHP code to gather all the info, then translate that into some number of days of trial period at $0, using variables a1=0, p1=<days> and t1=D.  Is there any other (reasonable) way?